# Two BindingSource objects with same DataSource property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dataview

I have some difficulties with understanding BindingSource's behaviour.
Let's look at following example:

1. Creating table

   `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

   `dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));`

   `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0 });`

   `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 });`

   `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });`

   `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3 });`
2. Creating two BindingSource objects with same DataSource property

   `BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();`

   `BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();`

   `bs1.DataSource = dt;`

   `bs2.DataSource = dt;`

At this point I supposed, that created BindingSource are fully independent. But really it is not so. **After changing `Filter` property of `bs1`**:

```
`bs1.Filter = "id >= 2";`
```

**`Filter` property of `bs2` doesn't change, but `RowFilter` property of underlying DataView** (`List` property of `BindingSource`) of **both BindingSource objects is changed**.

**It turns out that both `BindingSource` objects have exactly same instance of DataView i.e. condition `bs1.List == bs2.List` is `true`**.

My question is why they share same List and how one can change this behaviour?

EDIT:
I've found explanation for "why they're sharing same List?" - it seems that List is assigned from `DataTable`'s `DefaultView` property (so both `bs1.List == bs2.List`, `bs1.List == dt.DefaultView` are true).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that to change this behaviour one can create two different `DataView` instances for `DataTable` and assign them to `DataSource` property of two `BindingSource` objects accordingly:

```
BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
bs1.DataSource = new DataView(dt);
bs2.DataSource = new DataView(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet an expert in C#, but from what I've read I understand this:

by using `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` you create only one instance of that object. If that instance changes, it will change for anything that references it.

you'd need to create two instances, and set each instance of BindingSource to reference its own instance of DataTable like so:

`DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();`

`DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();`

`bs1.DataSource = dt1;`

`bs2.DataSource = dt2;`

Comment: No, I need to point them to same `DataTable` object. Now I've found answer. Will post it soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ruben's answer didn't work for me but pointed me in right direction.
I had to set filter in binding source to make it work.
Below is the code that worked for me

```
BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
bs2.Filter = "My Filter"; // Instead of setting filter on DataView, I had to set it on binding source.
bs1.DataSource = new DataView(dt);
bs2.DataSource = new DataView(dt);
//bs2.DataSource = new DataView(dt, RowFilter: "My Filter", Sort: "", RowState: DataViewRowState.CurrentRows); // This does not work.
```